# Suggestions for Entity/Business object validation where the validation is dependent on other Entity/Service

Tags: wpf, silverlight, validation, mvvm, entity

**Context**

For a WPF application using the MVVM pattern I validate my entity(/business object) using the IDataErrorInfo interface on the entity so that validation rules in my entity are automatically called by WPF and the validationerrors automatically appear in the View. (inspired by Josh Smith in this article: http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/using-a-viewmodel-to-provide-meaningful-validation-error-messages/

This works OK for simple validation rules like (name > 10 characters, value must be > 0)

But what to do when the validation rule in the model is more complex (like name must be unique / max value of the property is defined in another entity). I first thought of solving this by let the entity have a reference to a repository, but this doesn't feel good because I think there should only be references from the repository to the entity and not the other way (creating a cyclic reference)

**Is it 'legal' to have a reference from the Recipe entity to the ConfigurationRepository. Or do you have a better suggestion?** 
**Do you have suggestions how to implement Entity/Business object validation where the validation is dependent on other Entity/Service, like in the example below.**

Below the simplified code of my real world problem.
In the Recipe entity I want to validate that the maximum temperature is less than the value stored in Configuration.MaximumTemperature. **How would you solve this?**

**The Configuration entity** (Stores the maximal allowed temperature for a recipe)

```
public class Configuration: INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private int _MaxTemperatureSetpoint;
    public int MaxTemperatureSetpoint
    {
        get { return _MaxTemperatureSetpoint; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _MaxTemperatureSetpoint)
            {
                _Setpoint = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MaxTemperatureSetpoint");
            }
        }
    }
```

**The Simplified Recipe** (Class where the user configures a recipe with a desired temperature (TemperatureSetpoint) and a desired Time (TimeMilliSeconds). The TemperatureSetpoint must be < Configuration.MaxTemperature)

```
public class Recipe: INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private int _TemperatureSetpoint;
    public int TemperatureSetpoint
    {
        get { return _TemperatureSetpoint; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _TemperatureSetpoint)
            {
                _Setpoint = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Setpoint");
            }
        }
    }

    private int _TimeMilliSeconds;
    public int TimeMilliSeconds
    {
        get { return _TimeMilliSeconds; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _TimeMilliSeconds)
            {
                _TimeMilliSeconds= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TimeMilliSeconds");
            }
        }
    }

   #region IDataErrorInfo Members
    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get 
        { 
             switch(propertyName)
             {
                 case "TimeMilliSeconds":
                     //TimeMilliSeconds must be < 30 seconds
                     if (TimeMilliSeconds < 30000)
                     { return "TimeMilliSeconds must be > 0 milliseconds";}
                 case "TemperatureSetpoint":

                    //MaxTemperatureSetpoint < maxTemperature stored in the ConfigurationRepository

                    int maxTemperatureSetpoint = ConfigurationRepository.GetConfiguration().MaxTemperatureSetpoint;
                     if (TemperatureSetpoint> maxTemperatureSetpoint )
                     { return "TemperatureSetpoint must be < " + maxTemperatureSetpoint.ToString();}
       }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Recipe Repository**

```
public interface IRecipeRepository
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the Recipe with the specified key(s) or <code>null</code> when not found
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="recipeId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    TemperatureRecipe Get(int recipeId);

    .. Create + Update + Delete methods
}
```

**Configuration Repository**

```
public interface IConfigurationRepository
{
      void Configuration GetConfiguration();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For validation that is based on business rules, I usually expose a Validation Delegate that my ViewModel can set.

For example, the ViewModel for the Recipe might contain code that looks like this:

```
public GetRecipe(id)
{
    CurrentRecipe = DAL.GetRecipe(id);
    CurrentRecipe.AddValidationErrorDelegate(ValidateRecipe);
}

private string ValidateRecipe(string propertyName)
{
    if (propertyName == "TemperatureSetpoint")
    {
        var maxTemp = Configuration.MaxTemperatureSetpoint;
        if (CurrentRecipe.TemperatureSetpoint >= maxTemp )
        {
            return string.Format("Temperature cannot be greater than {0}", maxTemp);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The idea is that your `Model` should only contain raw data, therefore it should only validate raw data. This can include validating things like maximum lengths, required fields, and allowed characters. Business Logic, which includes business rules, should be validated in the `ViewModel`, and this allows that to happen.

The actual implementation of my `IDataErrorInfo` on the `Recipe` class would look like this:

```
#region IDataErrorInfo & Validation Members

/// <summary>
/// List of Property Names that should be validated
/// </summary>
protected List<string> ValidatedProperties = new List<string>();

#region Validation Delegate

public delegate string ValidationErrorDelegate(string propertyName);

private List<ValidationErrorDelegate> _validationDelegates = new List<ValidationErrorDelegate>();

public void AddValidationErrorDelegate(ValidationErrorDelegate func)
{
    _validationDelegates.Add(func);
}

#endregion // Validation Delegate

#region IDataErrorInfo for binding errors

string IDataErrorInfo.Error { get { return null; } }

string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
{
    get { return this.GetValidationError(propertyName); }
}

public string GetValidationError(string propertyName)
{
    // If user specified properties to validate, check to see if this one exists in the list
    if (ValidatedProperties.IndexOf(propertyName) < 0)
    {
        //Debug.Fail("Unexpected property being validated on " + this.GetType().ToString() + ": " + propertyName);
        return null;
    }

    string s = null;

    // If user specified a Validation method to use, Validate property
    if (_validationDelegates.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (ValidationErrorDelegate func in _validationDelegates)
        {
            s = func(propertyName);
            if (s != null)
            {
                return s;
            }
        }
    }

    return s;
}

#endregion // IDataErrorInfo for binding errors

#region IsValid Property

public bool IsValid
{
    get
    {
        return (GetValidationError() == null);
    }
}

public string GetValidationError()
{
    string error = null;

    if (ValidatedProperties != null)
    {
        foreach (string s in ValidatedProperties)
        {
            error = GetValidationError(s);
            if (error != null)
            {
                return error;
            }
        }
    }

    return error;
}

#endregion // IsValid Property

#endregion // IDataErrorInfo & Validation Members
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer! I like the idea of injecting the business rules into the model because this remove the dependency from the model to the Repository. 
The only disadvantage I see is that the model validation is now scattered through the code(in the model for simple properties and in the ViewModel for validation that depends ond other services) instead of being in 1 place(the model)

Comment: @ArjendenHartog You could also add the validation in whatever layer creates the object. For example, you could have a `CustomerRepository` which queries the database, creates the model, adds the validation, then returns the object to whoever called it.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I found that the baked in WPF validation methods are not complete and/or elegant enough. I find that using the WPF methods would scatter validation code and logic throughout my application and would even put some in my UI. Like you, I used Custom Business Objects (CBOs) for everything, and I was really wanting to keep my validation in my objects, since I was using them across several projects (a web service, UI, mobile, etc).

What I did was take my CBO (Recipe, in this case), and add some validation methods as properties. Eg:

```
    public Func<string> NameValidation
    {
        get
        {
            return () =>
            {
                string result = null;
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)) result = "Name cannot be blank";
                else if (Name.Length > 100) result = "Name cannot be longer than 100 characters";
                return result;
            };
        }
    }
```

After that, I decorated it with a custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class CustomValidationMethod : Attribute
    {
    }
```

then I created a Validate() method for object-level validation:

```
    public override void Validate()
    {
        var a = GetType().GetProperties().Where(w => w.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomValidationMethod), true).Length > 0);
        foreach (var a2 in a)
        {
            var result = a2.GetValue(this, null) as Func<string>;
            if (result != null)
            {
                var message = result();
                if (message != null)
                    //There was an error, do something
                else if (message == null && Errors.ContainsKey(a2.Name))
                    //There was no error
            }
        }
    }
```

then I created custom controls that support my validation. In this case, it was a ComboBox that I derived from the standard ComboBox and added this code:

```
    public Func<string> ValidationMethod
    {
        get { return (Func<string>) GetValue(ValidationMethodProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValidationMethodProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        if (ValidationMethod != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ValidationMethod()))
            SetControlAsInvalid();
        else
            SetControlAsValid();
    }
```

Once this is all set up, I can add field validation in the validation methods (which are stored in my CBOs instead of scattered throughout my code), I can add object-level validation in my Validate() method. As well, I can customize with ease how the control should behave with regards to validation.

To use this, in my VM I would call .Validate() first, then deal with any problems before saving. In my case specifically, I would store error messages in a collection and then query them (this also allowed me to store several error messages instead of the first one)

Comment: Hi CamronBute, thanks for your answer. I like the idea of overriding the OnPropertyChanged to enforce that validation is done automatically. I couldn't find an answer for my main question: "Do you have suggestions how to implement Entity/Business object validation where the validation is dependent on other Entity/Service, like in the example below."

Comment: You can add the validation in several different places. You can check in the ViewModel by creating a method, or put it right in the .Validate() method. I personally didn't have a method or doing this, but I would add it in the .Validate() method, since you know .Validate() will be called every time.